# How to load modules symbols to IDA while debugging a process

Tags: ida, windows, debugging

I am debugging a program that I compiled.
This program calls `SetWindowTextW`.
When I am debugging it with IDA I can step into this function, but it doesn't recognize anything there:
[image]

If I will load `user32.dll` (where the function is exported), I will see all the symbols and functions named, everything.

Is it possible to load the `user32.dll` to a process that I am debugging, so I will be able to see what functions it calls.

You can see the difference, in the left side is when I am debugging my program and access `user32.dll` and on the right side is when I debug it directly.

[image]

**Solved (thanks to Igor):**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try “Load debug symbols” from the context menu in the “Modules” list.

Comment: Thanks, I pressed the "Analyze module" and then the "Load debug symbols", it did the work